# Python Ctypes doesn't compact structure when field and structure fits

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

not sure if it's normal that Python 3.3.2 alwasy pack structure into a new structure unit. code below demonstrates the problem.

sts structure only occupies 8-bit. pkt only has 24-bit fields before status, so pkt should have size of 32-bit, not 64-bit. the printing of pkt clearly shows that Python packed sts into a new 32-bit integer and left 8-bit unused space with all other pckt field in another 32-bit integer

```
import ctypes
class sts( ctypes.BigEndianStructure ):
    _fields_ = [( "valid", ctypes.c_uint8, 1 ),
                ( "inout", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
                ( "exception", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
                ( "error", ctypes.c_uint8, 3 ), ]

class pkt( ctypes.BigEndianStructure ):
    _fields_ = [( "uid", ctypes.c_uint32, 8 ),
                ( "sid", ctypes.c_uint32, 16 ),
                ( "sts", sts, ), ]

print("sts {:d}-byte".format(ctypes.sizeof(sts)))
print("pkt {:d}-byte".format(ctypes.sizeof(pkt)))
a=pkt(0xFF,0xDEAD,(0x1,0x3,0x3,0x7))
print("uid {:02X}".format(a.uid))
print("sid {:02X}".format(a.sid))
print("sts {:02X}".format(ctypes.string_at(ctypes.addressof(a.sts))[0]))
for b in ctypes.string_at(ctypes.addressof(a),8):
    print("{:02X}".format(b))
```

another code to help explain the problem. the output of this code says that Python does pack fields in compact form, but a field with structure always starts on a new unit.

```
import ctypes

class sts( ctypes.BigEndianStructure ):
    _fields_ = [( "valid", ctypes.c_uint8, 1 ),
                ( "inout", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
                ( "exception", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
                ( "error", ctypes.c_uint8, 3 ), ]

class pkt( ctypes.BigEndianStructure ):
    _fields_ = [( "uid", ctypes.c_uint32, 8 ),
                ( "sid", ctypes.c_uint32, 16 ),
                ( "sts", sts ),
                ( "sts1", sts ),
                ( "gid", ctypes.c_uint16 ), ]

print("sts {:d}-byte".format(ctypes.sizeof(sts)))
print("pkt {:d}-byte".format(ctypes.sizeof(pkt)))
a=pkt(0xFF,0xDEAD,(0x1,0x3,0x3,0x7),(0x1,0x2,0x3,0x7),0xBEEFABCD)
print("uid {:02X}".format(a.uid))
print("sid {:02X}".format(a.sid))
print("sts {:02X}".format(ctypes.string_at(ctypes.addressof(a.sts))[0]))
for b in ctypes.string_at(ctypes.addressof(a),8):
    print("{:02X}".format(b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pack and compact fields sovled the problem. Only tried on Windows

```
import ctypes
class sts( ctypes.BigEndianStructure ):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [( "valid", ctypes.c_uint8, 1 ),
                ( "inout", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
                ( "exception", ctypes.c_uint8, 2 ),
                ( "error", ctypes.c_uint8, 3 ), ]

class pkt( ctypes.BigEndianStructure ):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [( "uid", ctypes.c_uint8 ),
                ( "sid", ctypes.c_uint16 ),
                ( "sts", sts, ), ]

print("sts {:d}-byte".format(ctypes.sizeof(sts)))
print("pkt {:d}-byte".format(ctypes.sizeof(pkt)))
a=pkt(0xFF,0xDEAD,(0x1,0x3,0x3,0x7))
print("uid {:02X}".format(a.uid))
print("sid {:02X}".format(a.sid))
print("sts {:02X}".format(ctypes.string_at(ctypes.addressof(a.sts))[0]))
for b in ctypes.string_at(ctypes.addressof(a),8):
    print("{:02X}".format(b))
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? For packing data in general (e.g. network packets or writing records to files), the `struct` module is far easier.

Comment: A ctypes `Structure` is meant for calling foreign functions. In general forcing 1-byte alignment with `_pack_` is only done to match a similar pragma in the target library. Otherwise you won't get the same alignment in a struct with varying field sizes.

Comment: this is not for network. I'm trying to make a common "header" of structs for a collection of C libraries. otherwise, I need to define over 100 sturcts those C libraries uses. C libraries expects structs with variable length paylod in unit of byte, so aligning to single byte is fine

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's compiler (or gcc with -mms-bitfields) won't share a storage unit for different integer types. However, with gcc on Linux, `pkt` does use just 4 bytes. ctypes follows the platform's convention, but you can only use an integer type for a bit field. For example, you can't use `("sts", sts, 8)`. If your compiler stores `pkt` in 4 bytes, you'll have to modify the ctypes definition to get the same size. The simplest option is to inline the `sts` fields in the definition. Using a `Union` would also work.

Edit:

Due to the way the constructor is written, you have to explicitly set the bits in the tuple, which can only be used with an integer type. It won't look at the contents of a previously defined structure to see whether it can be used to extend an open bitfield. In your example, look at the `repr` of `pkt.uid` and `pkt.sid`. `ofs` is the offset in bytes and bit offset into the storage unit. On the other hand, for `pkt.sts` the value of `ofs` is just 4 bytes -- no bit-field information is set that would be used by the `GETBITFIELD` and `SET` macros.

Here are the source links:

- [`PyCStructUnionType_update_stgdict`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Modules/_ctypes/stgdict.c#l299)
- [`PyCField_FromDesc`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l33)
- [`GETBITFIELD`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d047928ae3f6/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l422)

Since gcc (except on Windows) automatically tries to pack data to fill the bit-field storage unit (but on a 1-byte boundary, i.e. it won't combine a 28-bit field with a 4-bit field that's defined in another struct), just be careful to double check the layout when using bitfields. To adjust the ctypes definition you can inline fields, explicitly set the number of bits for integer types, or use a union.

---

FYI, while writing this edit I came across a bug. On non-Windows platforms, `PyCField_FromDesc` will continue a bit field even if you switch storage size. That's how gcc works on Linux, for example. But I've never actually used it, and this was actually the first time I bothered to look at the `GETBITFIELD` macro. If bit field switches to a smaller storage size, it uses the getter method for the smaller size combined with the size information (bit offset and number of bits) for the field in the overall context. That can't work in general because the macro ends up bit shifting to the 'left' by a negative number, which is actually a right shift that shifts out all the data, leaving zero. For example:

```
from ctypes import *

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', c_uint32, 16),
        ('y', c_uint8, 4),
    ]

>>> t = Test.from_buffer_copy(b'\xAA\xAA\xAA\xAA')
>>> bytearray(t)
bytearray(b'\xaa\xaa\xaa\xaa')
>>> hex(t.x)
'0xaaaa'
>>> t.y
0
```

Comment: my understanding is that ctypes should look at native size of sts and say "hey it's 8-bit and fit into the last 8-bit of the 32-bit integer". refer to second code, Python did it for the second 32-bit integer, but not the first 32-bit integer. construction between the first 32-bit and second 32-bit are exactly the same except fields ordering was changed. this is the part that didn't make sense to me.

Comment: ofs doesn't really mean anything, if I change sid and uid to ctypes.c_uint8 and ctypes.c_uint16 without the third bit sizing, then ofs of sid and uid will be bytes

Comment: the bug you mentioned is probably the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824617/python-structure-always-stuck-at-0-no-matter-what-value-you-assign-to-it but this bug was thought to only effect windows, so a patch was committed only for windows. you should check if it's the samethingas what you see on Linux

Comment: found an answer. looks like it has something to do with byte alignment by OS.