# ctypes c_uint32 getting passed incorrectly from python to Cpp

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, uint32

I am using python with ctypes to call a C so file.

The C structure is:

```
typedef struct {
uint32_t var1;
uint32_t var2;
uint32_t var3;
uint8_t var4;
uint8_t var5
} struct1;


If I call C code where I set the variables of var1 to 0x050A, var2 to 0x102 and var3 to 0x203 build it and print out the values everything works perfectly.

in C
static struct1 mstruct;  
mstruct.var1=1290  
mstruct.var2=258  
mstruct.var3=515
```

Then I call a c so file that prints out the values of the structure passed to it.

```
printf("var1 %lx\n",mstruct.var1) # var1 050A  
printf("var2 %lx\n",mstruct.var2) # var2 102  
printf("var3 %lx\n",mstruct.var3) # var3 203
```

Note that if I just use x instead of lx it wont build and gives an error.
But when called from C everything prints out correctly
var1 050A
var2 102
var3 203

Now If i initialize with python and call the same structure I define a class as:

```
class struct1(ctypes.Structure):
   _fields_=[
             ('var1',ctypes.c_uint32),
             ('var2',ctypes.c_uint32),
             ('var3',ctypes.c_uint32),
             ('var4',ctypes.c_uint8),
             ('var5',ctypes.c_uint8)]

   def __init__(self):
         self.var1=1290
         self.var2=258
         self.var3=515

if __name__=='__main__':
    mstruct=struct1()
    print('var1 {}  type {}'.format(mstruct.var1,type(mstruct.var1)))
    clib=ctypes.CDLL('csofile.so')
    c_rtn=clib.print_c_struct(ctypes.byref(mstruct))
```

the Var1 value is correct and the type is printed as class 'int' (not ctypes uint32).
and in the C so file it prints out
var1 1020000050a
var2 50a00000203
var3 20300000102

The lowest 16 bits of Var1 are the correct value.  The middle 16 bits are padded with zeros which are correct.  But there is an upper 32 bits from the what var 2 should have been in var1.  And Var2 started with the value from Var3.

There seems to be a mismatch like my python isn't really defining it as 32 bit but what makes it stranger is that the C is actually reading it as 64 bits and I don't understand how that could be the case.  Since the C structure defines it as 32 bit I would expect it to only take 32 bits so somehow it is seeing the 64 bits by python.

If I change everything to int it works perfectly in my demo application but the real C so file was created by someone else and I will get a new one every couple days so I am trying to avoid changing it each time.

I also tried casting when I set the value in the **init** thinking maybe I was overriding the type but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
self.var1=(ctypes_c_uint32)(1290)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

header:

```
#include <stdint.h>


typedef struct{
  uint32_t first;
  uint32_t second;
  int *marray;

} my_struct;

int call_c_function(int var1,int *var2, my_struct *mstruct );
```

C file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "c_header.h"


int call_c_function(int var1,int *var2, my_struct *mstruct ){
  
  
  printf("var1 %d \n",var1);
  printf("var2 %d \n",*var2);
  
  printf("mystruct first %ld \n",mstruct->first);
  printf("mystruct second %ld \n",mstruct->second);

  int *array_ptr;
  array_ptr = mstruct->marray;
  printf("C ADDR struct %p \n",mstruct);
  printf("C ADDR of pointer array_ptr %p \n",&array_ptr);
  printf("C ADDR  stored at array_ptr %p I need Python to match this!\n",array_ptr);
  printf("Value in Memory it points to %d \n",*array_ptr);
  
  printf("size of c int %ld\n",sizeof(int));
  
  for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
    printf(" %d ",array_ptr[i]);
    array_ptr[i]=8-i;
    }
    
printf("\n ");

  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with g++ -fPIC -shared -o clib.so c_file.cpp
And Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Aug 18 13:16:52 2020

@author: kevin.johnson
"""
import ctypes as ctypes
import struct as struct



so_file='./clib.so'


class my_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_=[
              ('first',ctypes.c_uint32),
              ('second',ctypes.c_uint32),
              ('marray',ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))]
    def __init__(self,ma):
         self.first=1290
         self.second=258
         self.marray = ma
         
def so_attr(sofile):
    from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
    
    out = Popen(args='nm ./{}'.format(sofile),
            shell=True,
            stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")

    attrs=[i.split(" ")[-1].replace("\r", "")
        for i in out.split("\n") if " T " in i]
    functions = [i for i in attrs if hasattr(ctypes.CDLL(sofile),i)]
    print (functions)    

def arr2list(inp,length):
    outp=[inp[i] for i in range(length)]                
    
    return outp
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    if 0:
        so_attr(so_file)
    else:
        mn = [i for i in range(8)]
        ms = ctypes.c_int*8
        ma = ms(*mn)
        print(type(ma))
        ma_p = ctypes.cast(ma,ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
        ma_byref = ctypes.byref(ma)
    
        mstruct_inst=my_struct(ma_p)
        
        print ('size of python int {} '.format(ctypes.sizeof(ma)/len(ma)))
        
        print(mstruct_inst)
        print('var1 {} type {}'.format(mstruct_inst.first,type(mstruct_inst.first)))

        
        var1=ctypes.c_int(5)
        var2=ctypes.c_int(6)
        
        print(arr2list(ma,8))
        
        clib=ctypes.CDLL(so_file)
        print('ADDRESS: {}'.format(ctypes.byref(mstruct_inst)))
        print('by ref ma: {} I Need C to match this'.format(ma_byref))
        print('map: {}'.format(ma_p))
        print('map2: {}'.format(ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(ma),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))))
        
        funct_int=clib._Z15call_c_functioniPiP9my_struct(var1,ctypes.byref(var2),ctypes.byref(mstruct_inst))
    
        print ('C Function return {} '.format(funct_int))
        
        print(arr2list(ma,8))
    
    
    print('done')
```

Comment: That sounds like the compiler is padding. Do you compile using a C compiler or C++ compilier? You could try to add `__attribute__((__packed__))` to your struct declaration. For more details look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: I was using g++ to compile the c code.  I will look into __attribute__.  I am not familiar with that.  Thanks.

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Show the complete C function and Python code to call it.

Comment: I tried adding the attribute to the C structure but the output had no change.  Definitely worth a try but didn't seem to fix it.  Thank you for the idea.

Comment: The C code looks like it is printing 64-bit integers.  If a long is 64-bits in your compiler then use %x instead.

Comment: Unfortunately the C code is provided to me and although I added the printf statements to debug why it wasn't working the use of the variables still have the incorrect values.  Which is what caused me to start doing the printf.  I could theoretically write a function that read the byte memory locations and re-write it but I assume I am doing something wrong on the python side since if I create the structure in C and call the library from C it works correctly.

Comment: @JulianH had me thinking that maybe the pack needs to be on the Python side so I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771150/python-ctypes-pragma-pack-for-byte-aligned-read but that did not change the results .  Next I am going to try the pack command from ctypes.  But I am not sure how to use that yet.

Comment: I also tried adding the bit width in the python structure as shown but it is giving me an error.   So not sure if this will fix my issue, but if it does it would explain that the cytpes declaration isn't doing what I thought it was.  You have to further define the actual bit depth...   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824617/python-structure-always-stuck-at-0-no-matter-what-value-you-assign-to-it

Comment: Mark if you want to post yours as the answer I will accept it.  I didn't understand it at the time but now it makes perfect sense.  The C code I was using had one thing in the header that was causing the issue that I completely missed.  It defined uint32_t as unsigned long.  Apparently the person writing the code was working on windows which treats it as 32  bits but I was doing it on linux that took it as 64 bits.  Calling it from C worked out ok, but Python was actually doing it correctly...  You were correct even though I didn't recognize it right away.  Thank you!

Comment: @MarkTolonen  Sorry. Realized I should have tagged you. If you post your answer I will accept it.  You were right I just wasn't experienced enough to realize you were right...  Sorry.

Comment: @KevinJohnson the thing is, C++ does not have a well defined ABI in which C does. So no matter what you are doing, I strongly recommend to use either `extern "C"` or `gcc` when exporting functions or structs from shared object files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long` on your system is 64-bits as exhibited by `printf("%lx")` printing a 64-bit integer.  As I see you found in the comments, your C code `uint32_t` was defined as `unsigned long` which would be incorrect on that system.

Your system should have a `stdint.h` header which defines `uint32_t` correctly for your operating system.